# hibernate could not get next sequence value

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a class that is a table within a postgress database. The class is then extended by the other classes. The main class has the following annotation at the top

@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="policy_action")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class PolicyAction {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  .....
```

the second class

```
public class myspecialPolicy extends policy {
    ....
}
```

when inserting into the database the following error is thrown

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist

I am not sure how to solve this problem any help will be grateful thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually using a sequence to generate your values? Or are you using an auto numeric field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was creating a **hibernate_sequence** table with **nxt_val** column with a **long** datatype in my database.

Sql 
`Create hibernate_sequence(nxt_val long);`

and then

`Insert into hibernate_sequence (nxt_val) values ('12')` **NB** the value **12** can be any number.

Now what happens is, hibernate will pick the value in the **nxt_val** to determine the sequence generation with specifying anything. It works for well for **TableGenerator, Sequence, Auto**

Answer (score 2):

If you use a serial value you should use :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="policy_action")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class PolicyAction {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="genName")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="genName", sequenceName="yourSequenceNameInDatabase",initialValue=1,allocationSize=1)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
```

If you want to use the Table Strategy, you have to create a Table with two columns (seqName and value, and sequenceTable for the table name, for example) and do this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="policy_action")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class PolicyAction {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.Table,generator="genName")
  @TableGenerator(name="genName", table="sequenceTable", pkColumnName="seqName",valueColumnName="value",pkColumnValue="policyAction",initialValue=1,allocationSize=1)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
```

Comment: for the first approach I am not sure how to do that as each table will have it's own sequence name therefore how would I override it in the subclasses?

Comment: Not sure it will work, but you can try to use '@Id' and '@Column' on the getId() method instead of the id property , then redefine your ID generator in each classes.

Comment: Additional information : It is preferable to use GenerationType.Table as it is portable with any SGBD. I had problem when i had to migrate a PostgreSQL to a SQLServer with the SequenceGenerator, which made us switch from Sequence to Table.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your version of Hibernate, one of these mappings can help you

```
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private int id;
```

On recent Hibernate versions (4.3 and later), you can use this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

Comment: I can't get it to work because of the inheritance it has to be a .Table

Answer (score 0):

One reason to this issue can be the PK is not connected to the sequence. For example if you perform migration from Postgres 9 to 12, tables and sequences can be generated, but pks in tables not geting value from seq.nexVal.
This cause `null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`
What I did to fix this was running this scrip to make the conection:

```
alter table schema_name.TableName alter column id set default nextval(‘schema_name.seq_name’::regclass);
```